# Why time complexity of following algorithm(cycle sort?!) is O(n)?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, cycle-sort

The time complexity of cycle sort is O(n^2) [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_sort)

However, the solution claims the following algorithm involving cycle sort only use O(n). Shouldn't time complexity be O(n^2) ?

```py
    def find_all_missing_numbers(nums):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :rtype: List[int]
        """
        i = 0

        # This is cycle sort and should use O(n^2)?!
        while i < len(nums):
            j = nums[i] - 1
            if nums[i] != nums[j]:
                nums[i], nums[j] = nums[j], nums[i]  # swap
            else:
                i += 1

        missingNumbers = []

        # O(n)
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            if nums[i] != i + 1:
                missingNumbers.append(i + 1)

        return missingNumbers
#
```

time complexity = O(n^2 + n) = O(n^2). Is solution wrong?

Comment: What about simply profiling the code with examples of different n to see if it is linear or quadratic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a cycle sort, the algorithm is designed to find absent numbers if an array consists of numbers in range `[1, len(array)]`.

```
print(find_all_missing_numbers([5,4,3,2,1]))
print(find_all_missing_numbers([1,2,3,5,5]))
print(find_all_missing_numbers([2]))
```

> []
>   [4]
>   error

This line assumes that proper position is given by a number stored, which may be valid only if numbers are in the range shown above.

```
j = nums[i] - 1
```

While cycle sort spends linear time looking for a proper position for every number.

Comment: In cycle sort, rather than having `j=nums[i] - 1`, it's using an iterating loop `j++` to find the correction position of `nums[i]`, which will take O(n) and hence O(n^2) for cycle sort

Comment: @jen007 That's right. This is the reason. The procedure in the question sorts if it has array of different all different numbers in range `[1, len(array)]`. Otherwise it might fail to sort.

Comment: Wouldn't there be at most n swaps and thus cycle sort time complexity is O(n)? https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/118802/121682
"There are at most n items in the wrong place. Every swap exchanges two elements that are both in the wrong place, and moves at least one into the correct place. After n swaps all elements are in the right place, and at this point there will be no further swaps. Therefore there are at most n swaps."

Comment: @AhmadFerdous not sure how your comment is related to my answer

Comment: @Yola Sorry my comment was not clear. You mentioned, "cycle sort spends linear time looking for a proper position for every number." For all numbers (1 to n) in array size of n, wouldn't there be total n swaps? The reference explains how it totals to n swaps.

Answer (score 1):

```
def find_all_missing_numbers(nums):

        i = 0 # Will happen only once so O(1)

        # no linear search for true position
        while i < len(nums):
            j = nums[i] - 1 # Will happen once per each iteration
            if nums[i] != nums[j]: # Condition Check Will happen once per iteration
                nums[i], nums[j] = nums[j], nums[i] # Will happen if if Condition is true so "c" times
            else: 
                i += 1 # Will happen if if Condition is not true so "c'" times

        missingNumbers = []

        # O(n)
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            if nums[i] != i + 1:
                missingNumbers.append(i + 1)

        return missingNumbers
```

So :

```
1 + Len(nums)*(1 + 1 + c + c' + 1) + n
```

if Len(nums) = n then

```
1 + 3n + (c + c')n + n = 1 + (3+C)n + n ~ O(n)
```